# I call a Stored procedure with 2 parameters (input and output) from C# but value of output parameter does not show

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, query-string

I Wrote a simple program which call a stored procedure with 2 parameters (an input/an output), code executed with no error, but value of output parameter does not show in output window!
My STORED PROCEDURE:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_return_orders_by_employeeid_and_show_order_count]
(
@empid int,
@ordercount int=0 output
)
as
select *
from Orders
where orders.EmployeeID=@empid;
select *
from Orders
where Orders.EmployeeID=@empid
return @ordercount
```

and wrote the below C# code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace DB02
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(@"server=.\sqlexpress;
            integrated security=true; database=northwind");
            try
            {
                connection.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand();
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.CommandText = "sp_return_orders_by_employeeid_and_show_order_count";
                SqlParameter inparam = cmd.Parameters.Add("@empid", SqlDbType.Int);
                inparam.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
                inparam.Value = 2;
                SqlParameter outparam = cmd.Parameters.Add("@ordercount", SqlDbType.Int);
                outparam.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

                SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (rdr.Read())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}\t{1}\t{2}\t", rdr[0].ToString(), rdr[1].ToString(),
                        rdr[9].ToString());
                } 
                Console.WriteLine("Numbers of Orders= {0}", outparam.Value);          
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                connection.Close();
            }

            }
    }
}
```

in Output:

value of "outparam" does not show!
Thank you for useful answers.

Comment: Your stored procedure does not actually assign a value to @ordercount

Answer (score 3):

I think you're using SQL Server (by looking at your C# code), so you shouldn't be returning the value, you just need to set the output variable to the value you want to return, like this:

```
SET @ordercount = 10;
```

Try changing your Stored Proc to this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_return_orders_by_employeeid_and_show_order_count]
(
    @empid INT,
    @ordercount INT OUTPUT
)
AS BEGIN

    SELECT @ordercount = COUNT(*)
    FROM Orders
    WHERE Orders.EmployeeID = @empid;

END
```

Comment: **Tank you** your answer is very useful.

Answer (score 2):

As per Sebastian's answer, assign @ordercount before returning it.

Alternatively, since you also `RETURN @ordercount` from your SPROC, you can also use `ParameterDirection.ReturnValue`

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/59x02y99%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Your stored procedure does not actually assign any value to this output parameter.
You need to change your stored proc and do something like select @ordercount = count(*)

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

RETURN won't set @ordercount (it sets a special parameter)

You'd need something like this to return *both* the resultset *and* the record count

```
...
as
select *
from Orders
where orders.EmployeeID=@empid;
SET @ordercount = @@ROWCOUNT;
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that you can do return @ordercount.

If you would like to get count if order. You should modify you store procedure as follwinf

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_return_orders_by_employeeid_and_show_order_count]
(
@empid int,
@ordercount int=0 output
)
as
select *
from Orders
where orders.EmployeeID=@empid;

-- Modify here
select @ordercount = Count(1)
from Orders
where Orders.EmployeeID=@empid
```

Answer (score 0):

I solve my problem.
I modify Stored Procedure as follow:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_return_orders_by_employeeid_and_show_order_count
(
    @empid int,
    @ordercount int=0 output
)
as
select *
from Orders
where orders.EmployeeID=@empid;
select @ordercount=COUNT(*)
from Orders
where Orders.EmployeeID=@empid
```

And in C# source code, close connection after SqlDataReader execution. then  open connection again, then call ExecuteNonQuery().
now output parameter has value. also i modify SqlParameter definition section, but it is not needed.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
namespace DB02
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(@"server=.\sqlexpress;
            integrated security=true; database=northwind");
            try
            {
                connection.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand();
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.CommandText = "sp_return_orders_by_employeeid_and_show_order_count";
                //SqlParameter Definition Section.
                SqlParameter inparam = new SqlParameter("@empid", SqlDbType.Int);
                inparam.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
                inparam.Value = 2;
                cmd.Parameters.Add(inparam);
                SqlParameter outparam = new SqlParameter("@ordercount", SqlDbType.Int);
                outparam.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
                cmd.Parameters.Add(outparam);
                SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (rdr.Read())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}\t{1}\t{2}\t", rdr[0].ToString(), rdr[1].ToString(),
                        rdr[9].ToString());
                }
                connection.Close();
                connection.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                Console.WriteLine("Numbers of Orders= {0}", outparam.Value);          
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                connection.Close();
            }
            }
    }
}
```

thanks alot for your helpful answers.